# Bootstrap Button Primary stays blue for a second when clicked or active, even when overwritten

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, button, colors, click

I'm trying to change the colour of a button to a custom colour. The button is using bootstrap's btn-primary class. I overwritten every possible state I could find and think of to this custom colour, but when I click the button it still stays blue for a second or two, before it changes back to the custom colour.

Here is the CSS I used for it:

```
.btn-primary {
    padding: 16px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #A8CC6B;
    border-color: #A8CC6B;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary.focus {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #A8CC6B;
        border-color: #A8CC6B;
    }
.btn-primary:hover {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #657D41;
        border-color: #657D41;
    }
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #A8CC6B;
        border-color: #A8CC6B;
    }
.btn-primary:active:hover,
.btn-primary.active:hover,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:active:focus,
.btn-primary.active:focus,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary:active.focus,
.btn-primary.active.focus,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary.focus {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #A8CC6B;
        border-color: #A8CC6B;
    }
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: #A8CC6B;
        border-color: #A8CC6B;
}
    .btn-primary.disabled:hover,
    .btn-primary[disabled]:hover,
    fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary:hover,
    .btn-primary.disabled:focus,
    .btn-primary[disabled]:focus,
    fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary:focus,
    .btn-primary.disabled.focus,
    .btn-primary[disabled].focus,
    fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary.focus {
        background-color: #A8CC6B;
        border-color: #A8CC6B;
    }
```

I have to admit I have no idea of what half of these do, and I think it is very ugly and I would be more then happy not to commit all this to sc. Appreciate if anyone have a better work around for this. Using a custom div instead of the button is not an option as per business requirement..

Comment: Can you create a fiddle? It will be easier to help you like that.

Comment: Sure i will create one, thanks

Comment: what version of bootstrap?

Comment: Oh sorry, I beleive its v.3.3.4
But I can see at least 4 different bootstrap versions in this solution :\

Comment: see my answer please

Comment: I wanna ask you something tho', why are you using `btn-primary` when you don't need the blue colour and shading? Why don't you create a custom button or use `<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Default</button>` ?? It just seems like a bad design practice to me..

Comment: ZombieChowder I agree. I would need to replace the button in many places though, this way it felt safer, but yeah its definitely not the right approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use `!important` to prevent override** (fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/7tydLgj3/2/)

```css
.btn-primary {
    padding: 16px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    color: #fff!important;
    background-color: #A8CC6B!important;
    border-color: #A8CC6B!important;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary.focus {
        color: #fff!important;
        background-color: #A8CC6B!important;
        border-color: #A8CC6B!important;
    }
.btn-primary:hover {
        color: #fff!important;
        background-color: #657D41!important;
        border-color: #657D41!important;
    }
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
        color: #fff!important;
        background-color: #A8CC6B!important;
        border-color: #A8CC6B!important;
    }
.btn-primary:active:hover,
.btn-primary.active:hover,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:active:focus,
.btn-primary.active:focus,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary:active.focus,
.btn-primary.active.focus,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary.focus {
        color: #fff!important;
        background-color: #A8CC6B!important;
        border-color: #A8CC6B!important;
    }
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: #A8CC6B!important;
        border-color: #A8CC6B!important;
}
    .btn-primary.disabled:hover,
    .btn-primary[disabled]:hover,
    fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary:hover,
    .btn-primary.disabled:focus,
    .btn-primary[disabled]:focus,
    fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary:focus,
    .btn-primary.disabled.focus,
    .btn-primary[disabled].focus,
    fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary.focus {
        background-color: #A8CC6B!important;
        border-color: #A8CC6B!important;
    }
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to avoid using !important but it does the job for now

Comment: you can create the button by your self without bootstrap

Comment: Yes I believe that will be the way forward